# AS2 - Assigning variable text and text color

Tags: actionscript, flash, flashvars

I have a flash file that contains text fields. I would like to assign the text fields via a flashvar as well as change the text color via a flashvar.

This changes the text color to red and works fine:

```
&textcolor=0xff0000
```

However this does not change the text color, but it does change the text contents correctly:

```
&textcolor=0xff0000&title=titlegoeshere
```

Here is my actionscript: - For some reason I have noticed that if I flip the order below and assign text first, color second, color doesn't work at all.

```
// text color
title.textColor = textcolor;

// assign flashvars
title.text = title;
```

How can I both assign color and contents? Could this be a bug in flash?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out - for this situation you need to specify a different title and variable name. You can't use the same one.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very easy, you have used the var `title` twice : as a `textField` and as a variable passed by `flashvars`. So to resolve this, you should change either your `textField` name or your var passed by `flashvars` like this :

**HTML code :**

```
...

<param name='flashvars' value='title_color=0xff0000&title_text=titlegoeshere' />

...
```

**AS2 code:**

```
title.textColor = _root.title_color

title.text = _root.title_text
```